# Did Bilbo and Gollum have different after-effects of being Ring-bearers?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, hobbits

Gollum (Smeagol) was once a Hobbit. His life was extended over 500 years while he had the Ring.

Eventually Gollum lost the Ring to Bilbo, who I think had it around 50-60 years (?).

At the end of the movie "The Return of the King" Bilbo has only been without the Ring for a year, but looks completely aged, wrinkled, suffers from poor memory, seems to lack energy (falls asleep on Frodo) and appears to be near death. On the other hand Gollum had gone without the Ring for 50-60 years, but despite his incredibly old age, he still had smooth, wrinkle-free skin and more energy than either of the 2 young Hobbits (Frodo or Sam).

Is this a result of the longer amount of time that Gollum spent with the Ring before losing it?

I'm basing my question on the 6 semi-recent movies; I haven't read the books but feel free to use them to answer this.

Comment: Does [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72599/3267) answer your question?

Comment: @Kevin Damn it! Yes it does. I hereby unofficially close my question as a dupe whilst keeping my precious upvote. No one should take it from me. The precious is mine.

Comment: Up voted your question and comment just for that. Love it. (Minus the missing accent on the name, of course..)